# Pagination query not working in laravel5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Why is the pagination not working when I use this query is that any differences in both the queries?

```
$users = User::all()->paginate(2);
```

Pagination applies only when I use this query but problem occur in index.blade it cannot fetch photo, created_at, updated_at from user I remove these three name from index.blade then it works fine.

```
  $users = DB::table('users')->paginate(2);
```

When I used second query than it cannot fetch date and error show Call to a member function diffForHumans() on a non-object

```
@if($users)
    @foreach($users as $user)
<tr>

            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td><img height="50" src=" {{isset($user->photo) ? $user->photo->file : 'http://placehold.it/200X200'}}"  ></td>
            <td><a href="{{route('admin.users.edit', $user->id)}}"> {{$user->name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Not active'}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                @if(!empty($user->role->name))
                    <td>{{$user->role->name}}
                @endif
                </td>
            <td><a href="{{route('admin.users.edit', $user->id)}}">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Please paste the code instead of the images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: $users = User::all()->paginate(2); when i used this query error occur Method paginate does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as:

```
$users = User::paginate(2);
```

And `User::all()` returns a collection, so you cannot run `paginate()` on that.